# bootstrap 4 datetimepicker format not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

```html
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/custom.css') }}">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js" integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
                                    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works fine according to your format. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: When I run it it still shows as DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM. Not for you?

Comment: No I tried in stackoverflow snippet and it shows 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' format

Comment: Are you using the versions of bootstrap and Jquery same as above code ?

Comment: That was it. I had another script before my </body> that was using another version. jquery/3.1.1

Comment: What is your expectation? The code provided by you is working. Please reframe your question